# How do you get to the .enter code automatically in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Okay I realize the question is ambiguous, but I didn't know what else to name it.  As all of you know if I double click a textbox in visual basic it gives me this code automatically.

```
Private Sub textBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textBox1.Click
          'do stuff here
End Sub
```

What do you click or otherwise have to do to get this to show up automatically?

```
Private Sub textBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textBox1.Enter
    'do stuff here
End Sub
```

What about this one as well

```
    Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textBox1.TextChanged
    'do stuff here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the textbox. In the Properties pane/window (press F4 if can't see it), click the icon which looks a bit ilke a lightning bolt to get a list of the available handlers. Double-click the one you want and it will create the template for you.

Comment: Thanks,  I realize I could of just copied and paste every time, but that would get very annoying.  VB is not the language of my choice.

Comment: On code view if you are in any of textbox1 events you can select any other from the upper right combobox and it will create it also.